# Do we need more of an automation analyst's time in BDD than we would need in a non-BDD project?

Tags: bdd, ui-automation

I am new to BDD and willing to follow BDD methodology for my test Automation projects. Do we need more of an automation analyst's time in BDD than we would need in a non-BDD project?

Answer (score 0):

The term BDD means behaviour driven development. It means development (not testing) derives from behaviour and that behaviour would be the acceptance criteria.

You can use the same scripts (Gherkin syntax ) for test automation but you need other tools as well (like selenium, WebUI etc.) to do actual test automation (For developer automation they can use the same business logic they have written to invoke from BDD scripts). So if an automation tester uses BDD then only thing they can do there is to create automation test scripts (in Gherkin syntax) and generate skeleton of the behaviour then to integrate with automation test frameworks. BDD is not the replacement of testing frameworks like selenium, QTP etc. Effort wise there will not be much difference (If you know test automation already) if you use BDD (Gherkin syntax) for your automation. One or the other place you have to write test scripts. If it is BDD then that will be Gherkin syntax in a file.

Comment: Sound great. Thanks.

Comment: If it helped can you accept the answer and vote up please :)

Comment: Be aware that BDD is about discussing business requirements (to potentially discover hidden requirements together). It is not about writing scenarios since these are just the formalized outcome of a proper BDD discussion and a way to automate the business requirements into a test.